# How can I find which process is eating my memory?

Tags: process, memory, buffer, profiling

My Linux system sometimes reaches 90% memory usage.

[image]

We are running some Java processes, and `top` shows overall usage as 45%.

If I stop the running processes, usage reduces to 5-10%. I want to list out which process is consuming so much memory, ideally as a table of process ids next to their memory usage.

How can I do that?

Comment: Hi Stephen, Is there any option to check which process/service is consuming complete memory?

Comment: Buffer/cache use doesn't correspond to a process directly, it's memory used by the operating system to avoid repeated disk accesses. It's perfectly normal for all your available memory to end up being used in the buffers and cache; in fact it's a good thing. Check the links given in the multiple answers to the linked question for details.

Comment: @Stephen - As per above link, its stating as OS will consume that memory, 
But my observation is, when the server is in 90% memory usage,  if I stop the running processes its reduced to 5-10% usage.
So i thought that some of the process is not releasing the memory properly.

How can i prove it, that system or processing consuming that memory?

Comment: Could you edit your question to add examples of `free` output in the different situations you're asking about?